# Как вывести имена всех людей, которые покупали морские продукты? Пример на SQL тренажере

Tags: sql

Пытаюсь разобраться в sql с помощью задачек на этом онлайн-тренажере https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all  
Исходя из базы на этом сайте есть задание:  
**Вывести только имена всех людей, которые покупали морские продукты**  
Насколько я поняла, для этого надо связать друг с другом 4 таблицы.

Структура  
Customers: CustomerID, CustomerName 
Orders: OrderID, CustomerID 
OrderDetails: OrderID, ProductID 
Products: ProductID, CategoryID

У меня получилась данная каша, в верности результата не уверена:

```
SELECT CustomerName FROM Customers where CustomerID in 
  (SELECT CustomerID FROM Orders where OrderID in 
    (SELECT OrderID FROM OrderDetails where ProductID in 
      (SELECT ProductID FROM Products where CategoryID=8 )))
```

Подскажите, как можно решить данный пример?

Comment: WHERE IN - это не только каша, но ещё и весьма качественные тормоза. Прочитайте ещё раз мануалы по JOIN, да повнимательнее. И прекратите мыслить итерациями - небось, не Бэйсик. В SQL мыслят так - сперва взять всё, потом отбросить ненужное. Т.е. множествами.

Comment: PS. *Вывести **только** имена **всех** людей* - это зачёт!

Comment: @Akina, после слова "всех" идет уточнение "которые ..."

Comment: @MaxU Вот именно поэтому здесь и не должно быть слова "всех". Либо наоборот, не должно быть слова "только". Масло масляное - это бред, но и масло немасляное - бред не меньший.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerName
FROM Customers
JOIN Orders USING (CustomerID)
JOIN OrderDetails USING (OrderID)
JOIN Products USING (ProductID)
WHERE CategoryID = 8
```